# Normal Python IDLE color theme for Conda visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to use the normal color theme of the python IDLE for visual studio code as it is more comfort to the eye:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this theme:

[image]

If you want to try more themes, you can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the Themes panel and then select `Browse Additional Color Themes...` to search.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can search up themes in the extensions tab. For example if you search up `anto.dafluffypotato-s-idle-theme` in the Extensions tab, you will find a theme that is very similar to the default python IDLE theme.

Hope this helps.